# Does Array2D have a bug in GetHashCode()?

Tags: f#

If you take a copy of a 1 dimensional array in F#, the hash code for both instances is identical.
Not so, seemingly if one does the same with instances of Array2D.

The following code is a Xunit unit test function, showcasing the potential problem.

```
[<Fact>]
member this.``test if Array2D has a problem with hash codes`` () =
    let a0 = Array2D.init 4 4 ( fun x y -> x * 10 + y )
    let a0hc = a0.GetHashCode()
    let a1 = Array2D.copy a0
    let a1hc0 = a1.GetHashCode()
    Assert.Equal(a0hc,a1hc0)  // fails!
    a1.[0,0] <- 42
    let a1hc1 = a1.GetHashCode()
    Assert.NotEqual(a1hc0,a1hc1)
    a1.[0,0] <- 0
    let a1hc2 = a1.GetHashCode()
    Assert.Equal(a1hc0,a1hc2)
```

Is there something wrong with my test code or is it really a bug?
Or is it by design?

Comment: It's the same for other .NET collections like array and generic. Even though [.NET says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode(v=vs.110).aspx) "Two objects that are equal return hash codes that are equal.", it apparently doesn't see two different arrays with equal contents as equal objects. This strangeness is part of the reason people enjoy functional programming which tends to have structural equality.

Comment: I don't think you're correct about 1 dim arrays having identical hashcodes.  It looks like the (=) operator does a structural comparison on them, but they have distinct hash codes. https://dotnetfiddle.net/2OykBu

Comment: I tested that in interactive (the 1D array case) and it seemed to work for my test array ``[| 0..3 |]``.

Comment: It's also not giving me identical hashcodes for 1d arrays in fsi, did you look at the fiddle?

Comment: @KennethIto Indeed you are right - it also fails for 1D arrays it seems: ``    [<Property>]
    member this.``Test if 1 dimensional arrays have a problem with hash codes`` (x : int[]) =
        (Array.copy x).GetHashCode() = x.GetHashCode()``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to look into the [Operators.hash<'T> Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/operators.hash%5B%27t%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D).

> A generic hash function, designed to return equal hash values for
>   items that are equal according to the `=` operator.

```
let one = Array2D.create 1 1 0
let two = Array2D.create 1 1 0

printfn "%b" (one.Equals two)                           // false
printfn "%b" (one = two)                                // true
printfn "%b" (one.GetHashCode() = two.GetHashCode())    // false
printfn "%b" (hash one = hash two)                      // true
```

Comment: Nice answer - I totally missed that ``hash`` facility. What I did in the meantime was to override ``GetHashCode()`` and ``Equals()`` on the record, my array is in. Along with setting some attributes: ``[<CustomEquality;NoComparison>]``